# What is the identity arrow in this category?

Tags: category-theory

This is taken from An Introduction to Category Theory by Harold Simmons (Example 1.3.1) (slightly changed for formatting reasons).

> The objects are the finite sets.  An arrow $f$ with source $A$ and target $B$ is a function $$f : A\times B \to \mathbb{R}$$ with no imposed conditions.  For each pair of arrows $f,g$ with $\text{source}(f) = A$, $\text{target}(f) = B$, $\text{source}(g) = B$, $\text{target}(g) = C$ we define $g \circ f$ to be a function $$g \circ f : A \times C \to \mathbb{R}$$ with $$(g\circ f)(a,c) = \sum_{y \in B} f(a,y)g(y,c).$$

I understand how to check that for three arrows composition is associative, but I am unsure how one would define, for example, $\text{Id}_A, \text{Id}_B$ such that $$\text{Id}_B \circ f = f = f \circ \text{Id}_A,$$

I know they would be functions from $A\times A \to \mathbb R$ and $B\times B \to \mathbb R$ but when writing down the composition I am not sure how one obtains the original $f$.

Comment: looks like matrix multiplication

Comment: The picture to have in mind is that these arrows are like the *graph* of a function (or more generally an arbitrary binary relation). Except this is generalized further, so that rather than "Is $P$ in the graph?" being a yes/no question, each point is weighted with a real number, sort of like "how much of $P$ is in the graph?"

Comment: In fact, @LordSharktheUnknown, it’s almost a matrix, but it is ignorant of any order of the basis elements (i.e., the elements of $A$ and $B$). Besides that, what is happening here can indeed be interpreted as composition of linear maps. More precisely, consider the (fully faithful) functor to the category of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, $A\mapsto \mathop{span}_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$; a morphism $(f\colon A\times B\to\mathbb{R})$ defines a map $A\to\mathop{span}_{\mathbb{R}}(B)$, $a\mapsto\sum_{b\in B}f(a,b)b$, which uniquely extends to a linear map on the vector space spanned by $A$.

Comment: The way it's written appears to have an error. Shouldn't it be $\sum_{y \in B} f(a,y) g(y,c)$? It is the sum of ALL those terms, including possibly the same value twice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the *Kronecker delta* $\delta(x,y)$ which is $1$ if $x =y $ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Writing down the relation that the identity $I_A$ would have to satisfy on one side : $$f(a,a') = (f \circ I_A)(a,a') = \sum_{a'' \in A} f(a,a'')I_A(a'',a'),$$
so a natural candidate would be $I_A(a'',a') = 1$ if $a'' = a'$ and $0$ otherwise. (This is known as the Kronecker delta function.)

Comment: Right, thank you for clarifying that this called "Kronecker delta" and not what I've written.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\id}{\mathsf{id}}$
You'd like a function $f: A\times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for any other function $g: A\times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, you have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f \circ g &= g & \qquad A\times B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
(f \circ g)(a,b) &= g(a,b) &\qquad \forall \,(a,b) \in A\times B\\
\sum_{y \in A} f(a, y)\cdot g(y, b) &= g(a,b) & \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

We can define $f$ in such a way that most terms in the sum vanish. In particular, if we set $f(a,y) \equiv 0$ unless $y=a$, then the sum collapses to a single term:

$$f(a,a)\cdot g(a,b) = g(a,b)$$

Then if we define $f(a,a) = 1$, we get the desired result: $g(a,b) = g(a,b)$, so $f\circ g = g$ in general.

The definition we've arrived at is:

$$f(a,y) \equiv \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }a \neq y\\1 & \text{if }a=y\end{cases}$$

which you can prove is also a right handed identity: $h\circ f = h$.